# Space in Vista Account Name Causing Error in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, windows-vista

I recently installed Cygwin without any significant issues. However, when I opened Cygwin and used the "./menu" command to setup kitchen, I got the following error message.

> Error: The folder name "/home/John Doe/kitchen" contains the space character.>
>
> This will cause problems with kitchen functionality and the the OS.>
> Please move the kitchen to a folder without spaces.>
>
> For example: /home/kitchen>

When I originally got my PC, I used my full name (ex. John Doe) for my Windows Vista account name. However, this decision led to the previously mentioned error message in Cygwin. I have since changed my account name by adding an underscore between my first name and last name (ex. John_Doe) and deleted the initial folder Cygwin created, but Cygwin is generating that folder with my previous account name. Is there some command that enables Cygwin to switch from a user's previous account name to the updated account name?

P.S. In case anyone is wondering, I opted to use Cygwin over Ubuntu because of difficulties I had getting Ubuntu 14.04 to run properly via dual boot on my Windows Vista PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the /etc/passwd file in your Cygwin installation. It contains the path to your home directory.

You should look for a line like the following:

```
John Doe:unused:1001:513:John Doe,U-JohnDoe-PC\JohnDoe,S-1-5-21-<sid>-1001:/home/John Doe:/bin/bash
```

and change "John Doe" to "John_Doe" wherever you see it. Or, if you prefer, you can just delete /etc/passwd and /etc/group and remake them. You'll be be prompted to do so and given instructions on how to do that the next time you launch a Cygwin terminal.

Comment: I used Notepad++ to make the changes you suggested and everything worked just fine. Cygwin created files based off my John_Doe account name, so now I can work in that folder without any with my account name. Thank you very much for your assistance.